# Why are questions that I deleted being counted as strikes against my account?

Tags: support

Why are questions that I deleted myself because they were being dragged off topic being counted as strikes for the purposes of a posting ban?

They weren't counted as strikes until after I'd deleted them?

Answer (score 3):

Your question concerned me because I agree with your premise that deleting one of your questions should not make things *worse* in terms of a [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

(I understand that [deleting old questions doesn't help *lift* any bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), but it doesn't seem sensible to punish deleting downvoted, unanswered questions you are not happy with.)

I was going to suggest escalating to meta.stackexchange.com - and, hopefully, getting some upvotes from other users to make it more likely to be implemented.

However, when I went to look at your question history, I wasn't so sure the question ban was triggered by your deletions.

[Links below to deleted questions are only visible to 10K rep users, and I believe the OP.]

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53644/ was only edited by you and deleted in September by the Community Bot.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53811 was only edited by you and deleted by you in September.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53887/ was edited by several users, including you. The edits by others were pretty minor - quoting the claim, inlining links, correcting typos and spelling errors - nothing that seemed to change the question. It was deleted yesterday by the Community Bot.
- [Did the US Government investigate paranormal phenomena at Skinwalker Ranch?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/) is closed but not deleted while we discuss how to fix it in chat.

So, you only seem to have deleted one question, it wasn't dragged off-topic by others, and it was about two months ago. I speculate the system is reacting more to both the closure of the last question and the fact the previous one wasn't fixed before the automatic deletion than the self-deleted question before that.

I don't have any insight into the algorithm, so this can only be speculation.

Comment: Don't forget that the system seems to see questions with zero votes as bad in addition ton downvoted questions.

Comment: You personally completely rewrote my question so that it asked about the paranormal. I think that maybe you should take a backseat on this one.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: Please at least consider the alternative explanation: I have offered polite, helpful and relevant advice based on my time on this site, my 100+ questions and 700+ answers, my mod status, and - perhaps most importantly - supporting references.  Dismissing my answer because I once fixed a poor-quality question in a way you didn't like seems *ad hominem*.

Comment: Could this answer be updated to include the score and breakdown of that score for all the deleted questions?

Comment: Why should the system not treat deletions of downvoted posts all the same? Letting people dodge a Q-ban or A-ban for sneaking in the deletion before the community can garner enough downvotes and delete-votes to do it would be easily abusable.