# 1 closed question this month = 7 day account block

Tags: bug

I've had one single question closed this month, with only 2 down votes on it at the time it was closed, yet I have a 7 day account block.

The FAQ says that this is the second highest level of block possible on an account, and yet I get it after one closed question with 2 down votes?

Surely this is a bug?

Comment: Based on the fact you have [two previous](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4884/39658) [Meta questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4886/39658) complaining about posting restrictions, I'm guessing this is simply an escalation of those restrictions. Question bans take into account your *entire* post history, not just your history from the past month.

Comment: @F1Krazy, I'm getting this every time, 100% of the time. I'm even getting it when I'm editing a question in an effort to get it re-opened. I got a 7 day lockout on my very first question. How am I supposed to get past this? just about everything I do results in a lockout, I'm not being given a chance to do anything because everything results in a maximum lockout.

Comment: But 7 days is not the maximum lockout, and you have been able to make plenty of posts already. As tim's answer says, a little more nicely, please make an effort to think before posting, because the community consensus so far is that your questions are bad.

Comment: @Nij, you can have a consensus of 3 people, the same 3 people?

Comment: If you're accusing users of targeted voting, raise it with a CM by using the contact form. Otherwise, you're making a strong assumption, and the likelihood is that it's many more than that.

Answer (score 6):

We don't know how the algorithm works, but it does take your full question history into account. You currently have a 4:2 ratio of negative to positive questions, 5:1 closed/deleted to open, and a total net score of -19. It's likely going to take a bit of time and work to get out of that. But you can post a new question in 7 days (which isn't that long).

Just make sure you familiarize yourself with the site rules to avoid further questions that aren't received well. Take a look at the comments of your not-that-well received questions, the [help page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help), the [FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users), and this helpful meta question about [What is a 'notable' claim?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim) and aim for on-topic and well-received questions (a negative question score, even "just" -2, is generally not a good sign; it can happen from time to time, but when it's a regular occurrence, it's a sign to reflect on why the community thinks these questions aren't a good fit for this site).

Comment: If you look at my past questions, around half were closed after a single user made changes to them, even after reverting the changes I can't get them opened again because the same people keep voting against it. It's the edits that seem to be unpopular.

Comment: @AaarghZombies your most heavily downvoted questions haven't been edited by anyone else. Nobody is interested in making questions worse, and I really recommend you check out some of the links people have been offering you to help improve your questions and answers.

Comment: my dashboard says otherwise.

Comment: [Your only visible question with a negative score](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/54124/) has never been edited, even by you. tim can see all of your history including the deleted posts. If they've checked and see no edits on your deleted posts, they're probably correct.

Comment: @Nij, I said "around half". That's in the other half. I have had several questions closed after users added in tabloid style claims regarding the paranormal, which weren't in my original question. One was closed after a user edited a question that was largely about land management to make it about the paranormal.

Comment: So, users edited to make them on-topic, you rejected those edits, now they're closed. The others, nobody changed, and they're closed. If you really don't see the pattern there, I'm afraid no amount of meta posts and comments are going to help you remove the Q-ban.